# Accessing Lists in Django request.POST

Tags: json, httprequest, python-3.7, django-2.1

I am having difficulty accessing all the data returned by my forms in my `post` function.  I notice a significant discrepancy between what is displayed when I print `request.POST` vs. when my code accesses this data.  Hopefully someone can explain this to me.

Output of `print(request.POST)`:

```
print(request.POST)
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['AXMPO...'],
 'start_date': ['2019-03-01'], 'end_date': ['2019-03-26'], 
'reports': ['4', '1']}>
```

In order to examine the data my code is dealing with I used the `json` module to view the data.  The behavior of my code during debugging conforms to this representation:

```
json.dumps(request.POST)
'{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "AXMPO...",
 "start_date": "2019-03-01", "end_date": "2019-03-26",
 "reports": "1"}'
```

It all looks pretty similar until you see the `"reports"` value.  The user selects these reports via an MultipleSelect widget on my form and my code is iterating through the id numbers provided.  However, no matter how many reports I select I only get one ID.  If anyone can explain why this is happening I would sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a really old school issue. I could wish this was more prominent in the documentation though. The explanation by Simon Willson is below:

"""

This is a feature, not a bug. If you want a list of values for a key, use the following:

`values = request.POST.getlist('key')`

The reasoning behind this is that an API method should consistently return either a string or a list, but never both. The common case in web applications is for a form key to be associated with a single value, so that's what the [] syntax does. getlist() is there for the occasions (like yours) when you intend to use a key multiple times for a single value.
""" - Simon Willson, 13 years ago.